# Is it possible to process a task at django-background-tasks without entering the command 'python manage.py process_tasks'?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to process a task at django-background-tasks without the 'command python manage.py process_tasks'? my task needs start when the application starts but I don't want to enter a command to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since Django in version 1.7 you can add `ready` function to your app which will execute only once at startup.

Let's say you have application named `StackApp`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class StackAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'stackapp'
    verbose_name = "StackApp"
    def ready(self):
        process_tasks.delay()
```

In your file `app/__init__.py` you have to include:

`default_app_config = 'stackapp.apps.StackAppConfig'`